# apps from google store on a windows device

Tags: windows

If there is an app available on the google store, but not on the Microsoft store, is there any way to put it on a Windows operating system?

Comment: Are you asking for [Emulators](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/emulators) (see end of that page for Android-on-Windows)?

Comment: no, different app

Comment: What different app? Without emulator, I'm afraid the answer is "no". Besides, we recommend software here (that meets *specific* requirements), not [howtos](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185). So could you please fill in the gaps for your requirements? What software are you looking for (if not emulators, it's pretty unclear), how much you are willing to spend when it comes to paid software, etc (see: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)).

Comment: Seems like I misunderstood - what is emulators?

Comment: Oh - I see its like an imitation software? So if it is not one of those then the answer would be no.

Comment: You cannot run Android Apps *natively* on any system other than Android. So you need something that emulates Android – an Android Emulator. Inside that one you then can run Android Apps. Just take a look at the end of the page I linked with my first comment.